# What is better performance between ManyToMany and a model with two forigen keys?

Tags: sql, django, performance

The case is I have a model `User` which is the teacher and student and I differ between them using a flag `type`, Now Teachers may have many students and vice versa so..

Which is better as a performance

#### Case 1:

```
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=1)
    grp = models.ManyToMany("self",blank=True)
```

#### Case 2:

```
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=1)

class Group(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='students')
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='teachers')
```

For sure I can handle this based on the type in the form.. etc, but
Now I can't determine which is better as a performance and code modularity

Comment: These are exactly the same. The many-to-many field automatically creates a linking table for you, which is normally hidden, but behind the scenes it works in precisely the same way. However I don't think either gives you the relationship between teacher and students that you want.

Comment: I know but asking which will be better to handle it manually by hand or through the M2M field, To be manually honestly will ease for me handling the code. so will it differ at performance wise .. I think that avg users will not exceed 300, which is v.small number